# Why EdsDownloadEvfImage() always return EDS_ERR_OBJECT_NOTREADY

Tags: c++, edsdk, liveview

I am having a problem trying to call `EdsDownloadEvfImage()` from the **Canon EOS SDK** in order to start the live view feature. It always returns `EDS_ERR_OBJECT_NOTREADY` which signals that the image data set is not ready in the camera or that the image data set cannot be obtained.

**code:**

```
    if(err == EDS_ERR_OK)
{
    err = EdsDownloadEvfImage(camera, evfImage);
    int i=0;
    while(i<20 && (err == EDS_ERR_OBJECT_NOTREADY))
    {
        err = EdsDownloadEvfImage(camera, evfImage);
        i++;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the live view before calling your code?

You need to set the `Evf_OutputDevice` property to `PC` (or simply something other than `Off` or `Camera`).
After setting that, it may take a little bit and then you should be able to download live view images.

Comment: thanks!  I am sorry there is a bug in the start live view .  I have modified the code ,but now a new problem has arisen.                                                  
EdsGetPropertyData(evfImage,kEdsPropID_Evf_ZoomPosition,0,sizeof(zoom),&zoom)  return "EDS_ERR_INVALID_LENGTH"